# Calling a function on every .py file that is not empty in every folder and subfolder in python

Tags: python, function, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I need to call a function "handledisclaimer()" on every .py file that is not empty in every folder and subfolder. Sometimes there is just one subfolder, sometimes there are two or three, ex.

```
Projects
    ->jenkins
      .jenkinsfile
    ->tests
      ->A
        ->A.a
          init.py
          test.py
        ->A.aa
          init.py
          Results.tar
          test.py
      ->B
        ->B.b
          ->B.b.1
            init.py
            test.py
          ->B.b.2
            init.py
            test.py
        init.py
      conftest.py
      init.py
      helpers.py
```

There are much more folders but of course I dont list everyone.
I have tried amongst under things something like this.

```
 def navigate_through_directory():
      for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/MuellerM/PycharmProjects/Projects"):
         for subdirectory in dirs:
              for filename in dirs:
                  fname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                  if fname.endswith(".py") and os.stat(fname).st_size >0:
                      handle_disclaimer()
                      continue
                  else:
                      continue
```

However, subdirectory in dirs justs lists one subdirectory.
I have found many proposals on stackoverflow how this can be done but nothing seems to be working for me. The root directory is "C:/Users/MuellerM/PycharmProjects/Projects".

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. If you want to run `handledisclaimer`  on every file then maybe you should send it as argument `handledisclaimer(fname)`

Comment: you have wrong `for`-loops. You should separatelly run `for subdirectory in dirs: ...` and separatelly `for filename in files: ...` , not `in dirs`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. At this moment you use wrong variables in `for`-loops. It has to be `... in file` instead of `...in dirs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it on your file but you use `for`-loop in wrong way, and you use wrong variables
import os

```
def navigate_through_directory(directory):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
         print('[DEBUG] root:', root)

         # - work with dirnames -
         
         for dirname in dirs:
             fullpath = os.path.join(root, dirname)
             print('[DEBUG]  dir:', fullpath)
            
         # - work with filenames -
         
         for filename in files:  # <-- files, not dirs
             fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
             
             print('[DEBUG] file:', fullpath)
             if fullpath.endswith(".py") and os.stat(fullpath).st_size > 0:
                handle_disclaimer(fullpath)
                
#navigate_through_directory("C:/Users/MuellerM/PycharmProjects/Projects")
navigate_through_directory("/home/furas/test")
```

Comment: thank you very much, that solved my problem :)